# Pandas - How to count successive appearances in a dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a column A and I want to create another column B that counts the successive appearances of a value in column A, like this:

```
 A   B 
---|---
 1 | 0
 0 | 0
 0 | 0
 1 | 1
 0 | 1
 0 | 1
 1 | 2
 0 | 2 
 0 | 2
-1 | 0
 0 | 0
 0 | 0 
-1 |-1
 0 |-1
-1 |-2 
 0 |-2
 0 |-2
 1 | 0
 0 | 0
 1 | 1
 0 | 1
 1 | 2
 1 | 3
 0 | 3
```

Comment: look into `cumsum` attributed of pandas Series. You will probably have some reset clause but `cumsum` should help

Comment: Successive appereance of what?

Comment: Could you explain a little better your output?

Answer (score 1):

In your case create the group key by using `ffill` with `cumsum` , then `groupby` `cumsum` subtract the `first` item of each group

```
g=df.groupby(df.A.mask(df.A==0).ffill().diff().ne(0).cumsum()).A
g.cumsum()-g.transform('first')
#df['B']= g.cumsum()-g.transform('first')

Out[303]: 
0     0
1     0
2     0
3     1
4     1
5     1
6     2
7     2
8     2
9     0
10    0
11    0
12   -1
13   -1
14   -2
15   -2
16   -2
17    0
18    0
19    1
20    1
21    2
22    3
23    3
Name: A, dtype: int64
```

Comment: @marcoswernicke if it work for you would you like accept it?